# How to size circle radius by the number of observations per zip code in R Shiny Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, shinydashboard

I have reactive data that I use in R shiny and currently plot observations by zip code on the leaflet map.  However, I would like the circle radius to be sized by the number of observations per zipcode.  I work in survey response, so it would be sized by how many responses we got in each zip code.

Here is the code:

```
m = leaflet(data = rs11) %>% addTiles() %>% addCircles(~longitude, 
~latitude, popup = ~htmlEscape(RESPONDENT))
```

Where `rs11` is a data frame that contains a RESPONDENT variable, the respondent's zip code, longitude, and latitude. The plotting works just fine, but its creating a reactive variable to adjust the radius of the circle I'm having trouble with.

Comment: where is the code you have so far?

Comment: `m = leaflet(data = rs11) %>% addTiles() %>%
    
      addCircles(~longitude, ~latitude, popup = ~htmlEscape(RESPONDENT))`  Where rs11 is a data frame that contains a RESPONDENT variable, the respondent's zip code, longitude, and latitude.  The plotting works just fine, but its creating a reactive variable to adjust the radius of the circle I'm having trouble with

Comment: Can you share the basic structure of your data? Is it already grouped & summarized in a way that would allow your leaflet circles to size correctly?

Comment: It is a data frame with the following variables: RESPONDENT, Entry_Date, Zipcode, city, state, latitude, longitude.  Its a merger of my respondent, zipcode, and entry date information with that of the zipcode package.

Comment: I likely need to attach a new variable that gives a count for the number of observations in the data frame that contain that observation's zipcode.